# Pyomo | Couenne solver | restrict indexed variable domain to two integer values

Tags: python, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I'm a newbie to Pyomo and struggling with understanding the intuition behind Pyomo's syntax and how it builds its models. This may be why I cannot figure out how to define and solve a 'binary' problem where **N** variables must take only ±1 values using Pyomo and Couenne solver.

First I tried the `Integers` domain with `bounds=(-1, 1)` and tried to add a strict inequality:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
N = 5
w = np.ones(range(N))
pyoModel = pyo.ConcreteModel('binary model')
pyoModel.o = pyo.Var(range(N), bounds=(-1, 1), within=pyo.Integers, initialize=1)
pyoModel.binaryConstraintP = pyo.Constraint(range(N), rule=strictlyPositive)
pyoModel.binaryConstraintN = pyo.Constraint(range(N), rule=strictlyNegative)
pyoModel.objective = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.sum_product(pyoModel.o, w, index=range(N)), sense=pyo.maximize)
def strictlyPositive(model, i):
    return model.o[i] > 0
def strictlyNegative(model, i):
    return model.o[i] < 0
```

This ends up with:

> ValueError: Constraint 'binaryConstraintP[0]' encountered a strict inequality expression ('>' or '<'). All constraints must be formulated using using '<=', '>=', or '=='.

Okay, no strict inequalities allowed (don't know why!), I tried to switch to the `Binary` domain and do a workaround by manipulating the variable in the objective so it lies with in {-1, 1} - i.e., if **o ∈ {0, 1} then 2 x o - 1 ∈ {-1, 1}**:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
N = 5
w = np.ones(range(N))
pyoModel = pyo.ConcreteModel('binary model')
pyoModel.o = pyo.Var(range(N), within=pyo.Binary, initialize=1)
pyoModel.objective = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.sum_product(2 * pyoModel.o - 1, w, index=range(N)), sense=pyo.maximize)
```

Got:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'IndexedVar'

So I used an array of twos and ones instead of 2 and 1 but got another error about shape broadcasting. I'm sure I'm missing something here because it should be easy to construct a linear equation in the objective right?

I also tried to change the domain into a user-defined one:

```
...
pyoModel.domain = pyo.Set(initialize=[-1, 1])
...
pyoModel.o = pyo.Var(range(N), domain=pyoModel.domain, initialize=1)
...
with SolverFactory('couenne') as opt:
    results = opt.solve(pyoModel, load_solutions=False)
    ...
```

and ended up with *Couenne* error:

> TypeError: Invalid domain type for variable with name '%s'. Variable is not continuous, integer, or binary.

I also thought of using SOSs but it was even harder to understand how they work!

Again, I must be missing something in each approach. Any help would be appriciated.

**Side note**: I simplified the original code as possible to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt fails due to use of strict inequalities, which is a no-no.  There is theory behind this as solvers of these types of problems work on the "convex hull" of the problem space.  For more info, pick up a text on linear programming--it is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer.

Your second attempt is on the right track.  It is completely appropriate to let x be a binary variable and use the linear conversion 2x-1 if you are looking for math equivalent of ±1.  Your attempt there is failing because you are declaring your `x` variable to be an indexed variable by providing an index in the `Var()` construct, yet you are not using the index in the Objective.

Here is an example that employs an indexed variable.  If you only have a singleton, then just remove the indexing set references.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

some_constants = {  0: 100,
                    1: 200,
                    2: -50,
                    3: 300,
                    4: 50}

m = ConcreteModel('plus & minus ones project')

m.S = Set(initialize=range(5))
m.c = Param(m.S, initialize=some_constants)
m.x = Var(m.S, within=Binary)    # creates {m.x[0], m.x[1], ... , m.x[4]}

# try to maximize the sum of x*c
m.obj = Objective(expr=sum((2*m.x[s] - 1)*m.c[s] for s in m.S), sense=maximize)

# some constraint to limit the number of "+1 picks" to 2...easy with binary vars.
m.C1 = Constraint(expr=sum(m.x[s] for s in m.S) <= 2)

m.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
1 Set Declarations
    S : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    5 : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

1 Param Declarations
    c : Size=5, Index=S, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          0 :   100
          1 :   200
          2 :   -50
          3 :   300
          4 :    50

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=5, Index=S
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
          1 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
          2 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
          3 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
          4 :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : maximize : (2*x[0] - 1)*100 + (2*x[1] - 1)*200 + (2*x[2] - 1)*-50 + (2*x[3] - 1)*300 + (2*x[4] - 1)*50

1 Constraint Declarations
    C1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                             : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf : x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] :   2.0 :   True

5 Declarations: S c x obj C1
```

Comment: Thank's for the quick answer! So where I missed it was the way I declared the objective. In fact, I wanted to avoid for loops because my 'real' case is more complicated: `xt * M * x`. BTW, does your solution scale to a matrix-form of the param `m.c`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why strict inequalities are not allowed is that it might not be supported by the underlying solution theory. I believe this applies to MIP. Did you try setting the limits to very small values within the constraints you defined? E.g.

```
def strictlyPositive(model, i):
    return model.o[i] >= 0.000000000000001
def strictlyNegative(model, i):
    return model.o[i] <= -0.000000000000001
```

emulating strict inequalities this way is not ideal as it might cause numerical issues, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Do you think this applies to Integers?

Comment: Honestly, I am not really sure it was a wild guess, sorry.